# How to remove a layerGroup in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

it is easy to add a layerGroup to a leaflet map by simply calling     `layergroup.addTo(map)`.
How I can I remove the whole `layergroup` from the map? I tried            `layergroup.eachLayer(function(layer) { map.removeLayer(layer);});`
But, the map begins to behaviour weirdly.

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use the [removeLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-removelayer) method, like this:

```
map.removeLayer(layerGroup)
```

Take a look at this plunker (click on the map to remove the layer):

http://plnkr.co/edit/jSUE8ft9p7odLhQGeOVa

Comment: Glad to hear this, it would be great if you accept my answer in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
layergroup.eachLayer(function(layer) { **map**.removeLayer(layer);});
```

use

```
layergroup.eachLayer(function(layer) { **layergroup**.removeLayer(layer);});
```

instead